# How many threads per logical cpu can IIS7.5 64bit handle at once?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

How many threads per logical cpu can IIS7.5 64bit handle concurrently?  I have heard 12 IIS processing threads per logical cpu but I have also heard it was 100 IIS processing threads per logical cpu.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry for not being specific but I was referring to IIS threadpool threads. That is when an http get request comes into my webapi server how many concurrent http get requests (per logical cpu) can my server handle at one time? I'm trying to calculate some threshold capacity numbers based on the number of requests my server can handle based on average response times from my get, which is ~500ms.

Comment: It depends what the threads are doing.  Consider using asynchronous operations to avoid threads altogether.

Comment: Agree with SLaks, indeed IIS by default will use 12 threads, however almost any dynamic content you have (whether PHP, ASP.NET, etc) will have their own thread pool that in some ways makes the specific answer of 12 threads not interesting. Those threads would only be used for content (async anyway) and handling the request to dynamic content handlers (like ASP.NET pipeline, or even classic ASP module) so it would be used very little. What are you running? ASP.NET?

Comment: @SLaks: Sorry for not being specific but I was referring to IIS threadpool threads. That is when an http get request comes into my webapi server how many concurrent http get requests (per logical cpu) can my server handle at one time?  I'm trying to calculate some threshold capacity numbers based on the number of requests my server can handle.

Comment: @JaJ: If you use async properly, that number is mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool

> There is one thread pool per process. Beginning with the .NET
>   Framework 4, the default size of the thread pool for a process depends
>   on several factors, such as the size of the virtual address space. A
>   process can call the GetMaxThreads method to determine the number of
>   threads. The number of threads in the thread pool can be changed by
>   using the SetMaxThreads method. Each thread uses the default stack
>   size and runs at the default priority.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx

> So for IIS 7.0 integrated mode, a DWORD named
>   **MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU** within
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\2.0.50727.0 determines
>   the number of concurrent **requests** per CPU. By default, it does not
>   exist and the number of requests per CPU is limited to 12. If you’re
>   curious to see how much faster ASP.NET requests execute without the
>   thread switch, you can set the value to 0. This will cause the request
>   to execute on the IIS I/O thread, without switching to a CLR
>   Threadpool thread. I don’t recommend this primarily because dynamic
>   requests take a long time to execute relative to static requests, and
>   I believe the overall performance of the system is better with the
>   thread switch. However, and this is important, if your application
>   consists of primarily or entirely asynchronous requests, the default
>   MaxConcurrentReqeustsPerCPU limit of 12 will be too restrictive for
>   you, especially if the requests are very long running. In this case, I
>   do recommend setting **MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU** to a very high
>   number.  In fact, in v4.0, we have changed the default for
>   **MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU** to 5000.  There's nothing special about
>   5000, other than it is a very large number, and will therefore allow
>   plenty of async requests to execute concurrently.

Comment: Thanks! What is defined as CPU?  I have a processor with 6 cores and 12 Logical Processors.  Does that mean it will use 5000 concurrent requests @6 or @12 units?